# qsort() vs std::sort, comparison function philosophical difference

Tags: c++, c, std

I was wondering why there is two entirely different approaches to specify the comparison function in `qsort()` { C version } vs the `std::sort()`.

`qsort` needs the comparison function like below: I don't know the reason why it needs three kinds of return values -1 , 0 , +1.

```
int comp(int *x, int *y){   
   return *x - *y; 
}
```

while the comparison function for `std::sort()`, which looks more consistent to me as it is written in terms of function to follows an invariant. i.e if x is smaller than y function return true, x is in the right position relative to y

```
bool comp(int x, int y){   
       return x < y; 
}
```

Why do we need three values -1,0,+1 when returning a bool (or int with two value 0 , 1) is much simpler and clean?

Comment: If you're programming in C++, then use `std::sort`, if you're programming in C then use `qsort`. Also, some C++ containers can't be sorted with `qsort` so then you have no choice.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg my questions is more related to the rational behind the qsort() comparison function. Why do we need three values -1,0,+1 when returning a bool (or int with two value 0 , 1) is much simpler and clean.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was indeed wrong with my approach. Deleted it so it wouldn't confuse anyone in the future.

Comment: @David because then you can distinguish `x > y` vs `x == y` vs `x < y` after one call to `comp` (in the first case that is).

Comment: @HappyHellowFace, and thats why you see -4 points in your name :(

Comment: @Drew McGowen, quicksort is not a stable sort. you don't  need to distinguish all three  x > y vs x == y vs x < y. so x> y and x <= y should be sufficient

Comment: @David true - it maybe because `qsort` was standardized before any notion of `bool` in C

Comment: Incidentally, `*x - *y` is wrong, e.g. if `*x == INT_MAX` and `*y == INT_MIN`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Others have pointed out the equivalence of the two ways of doing comparisons; here's why the two approaches are followed.

In C, the comparison needs to be a function pointer. That means you always get function call and pointer indirection overhead. When `qsort` was designed back in the 1970s on a [PDP-11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDP-11) computer, the amount of overhead had to be reduced so comparison functions such as `strcmp` did a three-way comparison in a single function call. (Note that `qsort` is generally an unstable sort, so the equality case may seem useless, but it can be made stable with the appropriate pointer comparisons.)

In C++, the comparison can be inlined at template instantiation time, so much of the overhead is gone (there need not even be a function call) and the simpler convention can be used. This also means that `std::sort` can work with `operator<` overloads by default.

Answer (score 2):

I'd wondered this same thing and came up with a theory based on `strcmp` and `std::string::compare`.  Namely, doing a comparison can take a relatively large amount of time.  To determine if an object `A` is less, equal, or greater than another object `B`, you can use:

```
if (A < B) {
    //do stuff where A is less
} else if (B < A) {
    //do stuff where A is greater
} else {
    //do stuff where A is equal
}
```

Which commonly requires the iteration of A and B to be done twice, once for `A<B` and once for `B<A`.  If you check all three possibilities at the same time, you only have to iterate over the strings one time.  Thus the `-1, 0, 1` convention was used.

However, C++ seems to have dropped this convention.  One argument I heard was that computers have changed, and due to the complexity of the code for doing the three-way comparison, doing one three-way comparison was slower and more error prone, and most of the time we didn't care about the equality case.  In fact, all the standard sorting algorithms are designed to work like this, though an individual implementation might do something more interesting.

```
if (A < B) {
    //do stuff where A is less
} else {
    //do stuff where A is greater or equal
}
```

According to MSVC's timings on [this test](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=7c3585e68cc374c71f36c2dbbc5a0c31-2aa6303d6d29a98a5ad6ee0073d8a74a), `string::operator<` is nearly twice as fast as `strcmp`, and calling `string::operator<` twice was only slightly slower than doing it once.  (Caching and simpler code I guess?).  GCC's results are similar.

Comment: "The test fails with GCC because G++ won't call strcmp 200000 times, it just calculates the result after one loop."  you can add in loop something if loop_counter%1000==0 && time(NULL) == 42 modify one string to kill the poor optimizer... :)

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl Or use `volatile`.

Comment: @JimBalter I think that takes hit on every cycle, my approach just does a mod and comparison... except on every 1000th iteration... - but TBH idk how exactly volatile messes up optimization

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl The whole point is to "take a hit" -- call strcmp -- on every cycle. You can guarantee that if one of the arguments to strcmp is volatile.

Comment: @ I meant that hit is reloading thing from memory instead of keeping it in register... because it is volatile, but like i said i could be wrong. :)

Comment: @JimBalter: Thanks for the `volatile` tip, that got the program running properly.

Answer (score 2):

If for any two x and y, either x < y or x == y or x > y holds, then two way of giving the comparison function are equivalent. One may define == and > operators in terms of < as follows:

- x == y is equivalent to !(x < y) && !(y < x)
- x > y is equivalent to y < x

As you may realize, it is generally more efficient (and simpler) to implement <, <=, ==, >= and > in terms of the *three-way compare* operation, then implementing == in terms of < as shown above. I think that should be the reason why C (and many other languages actually) chose the three-way compare function, even though quicksort might not exploit that extra information.

C++ has operator overloading, but no three-way compare operator (neither has C), so shifting from three-way compare to the 'less' operator (despite the above mentioned potential disadvantages) allows to exploit operator overloading.

Comment: Note that `!(x < y) && !(y < x)` is not always the same as `x == y`, although it is for all common cases. It all depends on how you define your `<` and `==` operators.

Comment: @MarkRansom They're equivalent in C. Of course one could make them inconsistent in C++, but that's such a bad design that it really isn't worth mentioning.

Comment: You are right that `cmp` would be more efficient, especially for things like `std::map/std::set` because these apply `std::less/operator<` more than once where one call to `cmp` would suffice.

Answer (score 2):

The qsort comparison function is modeled after strcmp and memcmp, which return < 0, 0, or > 0 ... which is more information than just returning a < or >= indicator ... it takes two such calls to determine whether two elements are equal. The notion of "invariant" doesn't apply here: obviously the invariant that a[i] < a[i+1] does not apply to the original array ... in fact it doesn't apply to the final array because a[i] == a[i+1] is possible. Nor does the term "consistent" apply ... the results are and must be consistent for both types of comparison functions. "cleaner" is in the eye of the beholder, and "much simpler" is an overstatement.

Comment: i don't think qsort() is using the three way comparison in any form. Two way comparison is sufficient here.

Comment: @David Yes, it's sufficient ... but that really doesn't have anything to do with your question, about why qsort uses a three-way comparison, which I answered ... it was modeled after strcmp; you do realize that the original qsort was written over 4 decades ago, don't you? If you want a version of qsort that just takes a less_than function, you're free to write one.

Answer (score 2):

There is an interesting discussion about this:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.c++.moderated/bgGrHG_Y_Pw